# Prevent overwrite SaveChagesAsync() when registering user

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I've created an overwrite of the `SaveChangesAsync()` method that allows me to track any changes in my DB:

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    //update DateCreated
    var AddedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
    AddedEntities.ForEach(E =>
    {
        E.Property("DateCreated").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
    });

    //update DateLastModified
    var EditedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

    EditedEntities.ForEach(E =>
    {
        E.Property("DateLastModified").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
    });

    //soft delete
    var DeletedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList();

    DeletedEntities.ForEach(E =>
    {
        E.State = EntityState.Modified;
        E.Property("Deleted").CurrentValue = true;
        E.Property("DateDeleted").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
    });

    return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
}
```

This works perfectly for what I need it for (i.e. updating DateCreated, DateLastModified, Deleted, DateDeleted fields in my entity tables) but I've just realized that this causes problems now that I'm trying to implement user registration and using .Net Identity tables.  The `SaveChangesAsync()` method is looking for the relative columns in my identity tables and I'm getting the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'DateCreated' on entity type 'IdentityUser' could not be found. Ensure that the property exists and has been included in the model.

Is there a simple workaround that I'm just missing?

Comment: [You can customize ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model). You could probably add the missing properties to the models.

Comment: As a note, it looks like you're doing multiple iterations of each of `AddedEntities`, `EditedEntities`, and `DeletedEntities`. Once when you do `ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(...).ToList()` and once again when you do `Entities.ForEach`. You could just run `ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(...)` (without the `ToList`) through a `foreach` loop and save your self one iteration through each collection.

Comment: @Joshua I've added the properties to a new ApplicationUser model that inherits `IdentityUser` and updated my db but unfortunately I still encounter the same error when trying to complete registration.